# How can I see the full backtrace using kgdb to debug an ARM Linux module?

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, arm, remote-debugging, kgdb

I worked my way through all of the free Linux training materials created by [Free Electrons](http://free-electrons.com/training/kernel/). In the last lab, we learn to use kgdb to remotely debug a simple crash in a loadable module. The crash is caused by a null pointer dereference in a memzero function call.

I am using Linux kernel 4.9 and a BeagleBone Black as the target, all according to the recommendations for the labs, and I've had no problems up to this point. My host is Ubuntu xenial and I am using standard packages for the ARM toolchain (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) and gdb (7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) debugger.

gdb is able to read the symbol tables from vmlinux and from the module with the bug in it, which is called drvbroken.ko. The module has a bug in its init function, so it crashes immediately when I insmod it.

gdb output:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __memzero () at arch/arm/lib/memzero.S:69
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) list 69
64      ldmeqfd sp!, {pc}       @ 1/2 quick exit
65  /*
66   * No need to correct the count; we're only testing bits from now on
67   */
68      tst r1, #32         @ 1
69      stmneia r0!, {r2, r3, ip, lr}   @ 4
70      stmneia r0!, {r2, r3, ip, lr}   @ 4
71      tst r1, #16         @ 1 16 bytes or more?
72      stmneia r0!, {r2, r3, ip, lr}   @ 4
73      ldr lr, [sp], #4        @ 1
```

The result is the same whether I build the kernel with CONFIG_ARM_UNWIND (the default) or disable that and use CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER (the old method recommended by the lab notes).

I tried the same procedure in kdb, and here I see a very long backtrace that includes the calling functions. The caller of memzero is cdev_init.

kdb output:

```
Entering kdb (current=0xde616240, pid 106) on processor 0 Oops: (null)
due to oops @ 0xc04c2be0
CPU: 0 PID: 106 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           O    4.9.0-dirty #1
Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
task: de616240 task.stack: de676000
PC is at __memzero+0x40/0x7c
LR is at 0x0
pc : [<c04c2be0>]    lr : [<00000000>]    psr: 00000013
sp : de677da4  ip : 00000000  fp : de677dbc
r10: bf000240  r9 : 219a3868  r8 : 00000000
r7 : de65c7c0  r6 : de6420c0  r5 : bf0000b4  r4 : 00000000
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : fffffffc  r0 : 00000000
Flags: nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
Control: 10c5387d  Table: 9e69c019  DAC: 00000051
CPU: 0 PID: 106 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           O    4.9.0-dirty #1
Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
Backtrace:

... pruned function calls related to kdb itself ...

[<c08326cc>] (do_page_fault) from [<c010138c>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0xbc)
 r10:bf000240 r9:de676000 r8:de677d50 r7:00000000 r6:c08326cc r5:00000817
 r4:c0d0bb2c
[<c0101350>] (do_DataAbort) from [<c0831d04>] (__dabt_svc+0x64/0xa0)
Exception stack(0xde677d50 to 0xde677d98)
7d40:                                     00000000 fffffffc 00000000 00000000
7d60: 00000000 bf0000b4 de6420c0 de65c7c0 00000000 219a3868 bf000240 de677dbc
7d80: 00000000 de677da4 00000000 c04c2be0 00000013 ffffffff
 r8:00000000 r7:de677d84 r6:ffffffff r5:00000013 r4:c04c2be0

[<c02bf44c>] (cdev_init) from [<bf002048>] (init_module+0x48/0xb4 [drvbroken])
 r5:bf002000 r4:bf000480
[<bf002000>] (init_module [drvbroken]) from [<c01018d4>] (do_one_initcall+0x44/0x180)
 r5:bf002000 r4:ffffe000
[<c0101890>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c024fa2c>] (do_init_module+0x64/0x1d8)
 r8:00000001 r7:de65c7c0 r6:de6420c0 r5:c0dbfa84 r4:bf000240
[<c024f9c8>] (do_init_module) from [<c01e10e8>] (load_module+0x1d6c/0x23d8)
 r6:c0d0512c r5:c0dbfa84 r4:c0d4c70f
[<c01df37c>] (load_module) from [<c01e18ac>] (SyS_init_module+0x158/0x17c)
 r10:00000051 r9:de676000 r8:e0a95100 r7:00000000 r6:000ac118 r5:00004100
```

It is pretty easy to figure out where to look for the bug with this information, but alas, it is not possible to get a line number or list the source directly from kdb. This is much easier in gdb, assuming that I can get a full backtrace.